# Meaning of 0_0 in Java 7

Tags: java

I have read that in Java7, we can now write this funny statement :

```
public static boolean isZero(int O_O){
  return O_O == 0_0;
}
```

The question is : What exactly does `0_0` mean in this context ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Comment: I'm getting flashbacks to Fortran which allowed spaces in numbers for "readability"

Comment: @Colin Yes, and it obvisouly works. I was actually wondering what was the semantic difference between 0 and 0_0. According to the answers, it seems to only be a question of readability.

Comment: Note that `0_8` != `8`.

Comment: @arshajii: `0_8` is a compiler error ;) So that shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: @jlordo Yes, that's my point. `0_0` is really an octal int literal.

Comment: @arshajii: Ok, a better example would be `0_12 != 12`, as it would at least compile ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Underscore characters in numerical literals are allowed in Java 7 just for the readibility purpose. From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can
>   appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature
>   enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric
>   literals, which can improve the readability of your code

Comment: Wow, look at that number climb!

Comment: O what the heck! +1 from me X_X

Comment: When I see a number climb I cannot resist contributing

Answer (score 15):

In Java 7 you can add underscores to increase the readability of number literals:

```
int oldMillion = 1000000;
int newMillion = 1_000_000;
```

It's especially useful with binary data:

```
byte oldMax = 0b01111111;
byte newMax = 0b0111_1111;
```

Answer (score 8):

Underscores are [valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) in numbers as long as they aren't the first character, last character, or directly on either side of `0x`, `0b`<sup>1</sup>, etc. Basically between digits.

For example, `4_294_967_296` is a more standard use of this.

Your code will check if the int passed is equal to zero.

However, this is not a decimal int, but rather, an octal int. `0_12` does not equal `12` or `1_2`. Instead, the former is equal to 10 in decimal.

<sup>1</sup> Binary literals were added in Java 1.7.